# Reading Jetty request body results in IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jetty, tomcat7, embedded-jetty

We have recently started running our application using Jetty 9.1.0 in development. The same application is run using Tomcat 7 in production. Whenever a POST request happens we read the request body using:

```
private static String readRequestData(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
{
    BufferedReader r = request.getReader();
    if (request.getContentLength() > 0)
    {
        int len = request.getContentLength();

        char[] buf = new char[len];
        int read = 0;
        int readTo = 0;
        while (read > -1)
        {
            read = r.read(buf, readTo, 1000);
            readTo += read;
        }
        return new String(buf);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Under Tomcat the BufferedReader object is a org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader and the data is read correctly. Under Jetty the reader is a org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request and this results in an java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException the second time through the loop. Just calling read the second time throws the exception. I can't even step into read the second time through the loop, which is confusing.

Can anyone provide guidance on what we are doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char[] buf = new char[len];
        int read = 0;
        int readTo = 0;
        while (read > -1)
        {
            read = r.read(buf, readTo, 1000);
            readTo += read;
        }
```

In above code you are reading the content from '`request.getReader`'and method `read` 1000 characters into a specifed array `buf`, started from `readTo`.As the loop increases the minimum requirement of the char size increase as `1000+readTo+........`

```
1st Iteration -> char elements are added from index 0 - 1000
2nd Iteration -> char elements are added from index 1000 - 2000
```

So if issue arise in 2nd iteration can check that the size of the array must be greater than 2000

Comment: The char array is the destination. Remember that this code works under Tomcat, so the difference is in the BufferedReader implementation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[], int, int)

Comment: What you have suggested did work. It's curious that the CoyoteReader knows to stop at the end of buf but the Jetty implementation does not.